# Place button at the bottom right corner of the parent div, not page

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out how to place a button at the bottom right corner of the parent div. The solution I found does that for the corner of the page, and that's not what I need. Could you help, please?

```css
.tile {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.my_img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <p>some text</p>
  <button class="my_img">My Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `position:relative` to class tile

```css
.tile {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position:relative;
}

.my_img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <p>some text</p>
  <button class="my_img">My Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a position relative to the parent div and it will work

```
.tile {
      background-color: grey;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      position : relative;
    }

.my_img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```